# XSS Inside the text part of an <a> tag

Tags: xss, web

How do I xss inside `<a href="https://gooogle.com">here</a>` ? I have tried normally using alert() but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Well, without context this is a bit tough--where did you add the `alert()`?

If you have control over the full `<a>` tag then you can simply add an event listener like `onmouseover="alert('xxs'")"`

However, there is some niche use where if you only have control over the `href=` attribute value that you could even try replacing the URL with `javascript:alert(1)` and it can trigger a XXS.

I hope this helps!